# Using other markup languages with maven doxia books

Tags: maven, markdown, doxia

I know it is possible to write my maven site in markdown, using e.g.

http://code.google.com/p/doxia-module-markdown/wiki/Usage

Is it also possible to create books written in markdown or rest? I couldn't make this work using book-descriptors as described in

http://maven.apache.org/doxia/book/index.html

How do I tell doxia in which markup language my sections are written?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate book from markdown using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc)

Doxia is a small tool which covers to generate simple html only

But you should be able to generate maven site and books using same markdown.

Comment: It is possible to generate to multiple formats using doxia-maven-plugin. See: http://maven.apache.org/doxia/book/index.html